# Outliers' colours do not match their corresponding Boxplot colour

Tags: pgfplots, color, boxplot

can you give me some help here?

I'm using custom colours for each axis of my boxplot, but their outliers do not match that color.

This is what I have so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics} 

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        boxplot/draw direction = y,
        x axis line style = {opacity=0},
        axis x line* = bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        enlarge y limits,
        ymajorgrids,
        xtick = {1, 2, 3, 4},
        xticklabel style = {align=center, font=\small},
        xticklabels = {A, B, C, D},
        xtick style = {draw=none},
        ylabel = {LoC},
    ]

    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=1,
      lower quartile=2,
      median=3,
      upper quartile=4,
      upper whisker=5
    },
    color=green,
    fill=green, 
    draw=black
    ] coordinates {(0, 6)};
    
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=0.5,
      lower quartile=2,
      median=3,
      upper quartile=3.5,
      upper whisker=5
    },
    color=blue,
    fill=blue, 
    draw=black
    ] coordinates {(0, 5.7)};
    
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=0,
      lower quartile=1,
      median=2,
      upper quartile=4,
      upper whisker=5.5
    },
    color=red,
    fill=red, 
    draw=black
    ] coordinates {(0, 6)};
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And this the result that I got

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Humberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems the colors for the `mark`s have to be given extra with the `mark options` (see MWE below).

Interestingly changing `\addplot+` to (just) `\addplot` the outliers aren't shown at all. Together with the "strange" behaviour of `\addplot+` not considering the colors given to the not-outlier stuff this may be a bug. Is you think so as well, please consider adding an issue to the [PGFPlots issue tracker](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues).

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
    ]

        \addplot+[
            boxplot prepared={
                lower whisker=1,
                lower quartile=2,
                median=3,
                upper quartile=4,
                upper whisker=5,
            },
            fill=green,
            draw=black,
            % ==============
            % added
            mark options={
                fill=green,
                draw=black,
            },
            % ==============
        ] coordinates {(0, 6)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Stefan many thanks for your help . I will do what you suggested. Thanks for your time